# Console prints but not response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im trying to restructure a complex JSON Array using node.js, below is my code

```
let n = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr2));
async.forEachOf(n, function(value, key, cb1) {
let obj = [];
async.forEachOf(value.flightDetail.flightDetails, function(v, k, cb2) {
    let dateTimeInfo = v.flightInformation.productDateTime;
    let isNextDay = ((dateTimeInfo.dateVariation) ? true : false);
    let sectorInf = v.flightInformation.location;
    let flightDetails = {};
    flightDetails.eType = v.flightInformation.productDetail.equipmentType;
    flightDetails.marketingCarrier = v.flightInformation.companyId.marketingCarrier;
    flightDetails.operatingCarrier = v.flightInformation.companyId.operatingCarrier || v.flightInformation.companyId.marketingCarrier;
    obj['segment-' + ((k) + 1)] = {
        departureDate: dateTimeInfo.dateOfDeparture,
        arrivalDate: dateTimeInfo.dateOfArrival,
        departureTime: dateTimeInfo.timeOfDeparture,
        arrivalTime: dateTimeInfo.timeOfArrival,
        isNextDay: isNextDay,
        sourceSector: sectorInf[0].locationId,
        sourceTerminal: sectorInf[0].terminal || "",
        desitinationSector: sectorInf[1].locationId,
        desitinationTerminal: sectorInf[1].terminal || "",
        flightInfo: flightDetails
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); **-- This doesn't working** 
    console.log(obj); **-- this does work** 
    cb2();
}, function() {
    arr3.push({
        flight: obj,
        price: value.priceObject
    });
    cb1();
  });
}, function() {
callback();
});
```

When im trying to output the final **arr3** response for some reason it doesn't seems to be working. But when i console it, its printing properly.

Is it something to do with promise/async.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle ?

Comment: Are you making any async calls? I'm trying to figure out why you're using `async.forEachOf` instead of something synchronous. Also, what's specifically not working?

Comment: where are you printing the array ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this peace of code `obj['segment-' + ((k) + 1)]` which caused the problem, i don't know why that happened. By changing that to a straightforward return statement it solved the issue.

**Working Sample:**

```
let n = _.map(dataArray, function(flightObjectVal) {
  let flightObj = flightObjectVal.flightDetail.flightDetails;
  let pricedObj = flightObjectVal.priceObject;
  return {
    flight: _.map(flightObj, function(v) {
      //    Incase of flightInformation key is missing in the response object append with one.
      if (!v.flightInformation) {
        v.flightInformation = v;
      }

      //    Date & Time object
      let dateTimeInfo = v.flightInformation.productDateTime;

      //    Is the flight next day
      let isNextDay = ((dateTimeInfo.dateVariation) ? true : false);

      //    Flight sector object
      let sectorInf = v.flightInformation.location;

      //    Define restructured flight detials object
      let flightDetails = {};

      //    Flight Equipment type
      flightDetails.eType = v.flightInformation.productDetail.equipmentType;

      //    Marketing airline code 
      flightDetails.marketingCarrier = v.flightInformation.companyId.marketingCarrier;

      //    Operating airline code 
      flightDetails.operatingCarrier = v.flightInformation.companyId.operatingCarrier || v.flightInformation.companyId.marketingCarrier;

      //Return the final restructured object
      return {
        departureDate: dateTimeInfo.dateOfDeparture,
        arrivalDate: dateTimeInfo.dateOfArrival,
        departureTime: dateTimeInfo.timeOfDeparture,
        arrivalTime: dateTimeInfo.timeOfArrival,
        isNextDay: isNextDay,
        sourceSector: sectorInf[0].locationId,
        sourceTerminal: sectorInf[0].terminal || "",
        desitinationSector: sectorInf[1].locationId,
        desitinationTerminal: sectorInf[1].terminal || "",
        flightInfo: flightDetails
      }
    }),
    pricedObj: pricedObj
  }
});
```

I did some refactoring using lodash, and thanks to [marvel308](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989284/marvel308) for pointing out the `async.forEachOf` synchronous concern. That made me re-think the whole logic.